# Issue with a socket program in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that prompts the user to enter a URL but I can't figure out how to send the entered URL in the get request in the 10th line of this code.

```
import socket

inp = input('Enter a URL: ')
ipt = inp.split('/')
inu = ipt[2]


mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((inu, 80))
cmd = 'GET  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

**UPDATE:**
I was going through my old questions here and found this silly question I asked in my early programming days. If anyone's having the same roadblock just use `String.format()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urllib` library.

```
import urllib

url = input("Enter url: ")
url_parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
domain = url_parsed.netloc
if not domain:
    raise Exception("Invalid URL")

# Use this domain to connect
```

Comment: I know I can use urllib but I'm trying to do it with sockets. Plus I'm a noob in python so I'm not familiar with some of the functions you've suggested.